# Host Another ROOT.war Tomcat App

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat is currently hosting my in-production `ROOT.war` app.

I need to test out a new `ROOT.war,` but I don't want to stop my in-production app from running. Note that the app needs to be deployed in the `ROOT` folder.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Deploy in under another context or try virtual hosts http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Comment: You test application on your production server? That's where the problem is. Use the production server for production. And another test server for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat can do name-based virtual hosting the same as Apache HTTPD.  You need to

- add a second `<Host>` element to your `server.xml`, inside the same `Engine` but with a different value for the `name` and the `appBase`

```xml
<Host name="app2.example.com" appBase="app2-webapps"
   unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false"/>
```

- put your second ROOT.war in `app2-webapps`
- if your Tomcat is behind a reverse proxy, make sure the `Host` header is passed through untouched (for Apache HTTPD with mod_proxy this means setting `ProxyPreserveHost On`

Now requests for `http://app2.example.com/*` will be handled by your new app, and requests for any other hostname will go to the old one.

I use this technique for hosting several different production applications in one Tomcat, but I wouldn't recommend using the same Tomcat for a mixture of production and development/test applications.  Instead it's safer to use a different server, or a second Tomcat instance running on a different port.

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to `mod_jk` for your answer to work?

Comment: @Kevin You don't need to configure anything to make it preserve the Host header (mod_jk does that anyway), but you might need to add an appropriate ServerAlias if your HTTPD is doing name-based virtual hosting.

Comment: what do you mean by `it's safer to use a different server`?

Comment: @Kevin only that if your test app is running in the same Tomcat as your production one and it gets a fatal error of some kind (out of PermGen or segfault in a native library or something like that) then it will take down the production app as well.  You should consider isolating it in a separate Tomcat process at least.

Comment: since I'm using Apache, Tomcat & mod_jk, do I need to touch any of Apache's config? I'm using SSL so it's IP-based virtual hosting

Comment: @Kevin I don't know. What matters to make the Tomcat vhost thing working is the Host header. As long as your Apache responds to (at least) two different hostnames and passes them both through to the same Tomcat port then it'll work.